# Controlling Sony CamCorder

Tags: api, camera, sony

Is it possible to control functionality of eg. PJ620 over wifi using the Remote API similar to other Sony Cameras? PlayMemories Mobile is able to control zoom etc. so technically I know that it is possible, but if you want to do this from your own app, what is the best option?
I am developing an application where I would like to use a Cam Corder due to it superior image stabilizing functionality and I would like to control it over wifi instead of resorting to Lanc. Especially since Wifi would allow me to transfer the recorded material in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the PJ620 is not supported.  You can see a list of cameras that support the API here:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/cameras/